# Closing a TCP connection in an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I recognized some strange behavior with a socket stream connection in android. I would like to know why its different from Java.

In my `AsyncTask` I open a `client socket` and an `inputstream` with a `bufferedreader` for a `TCP` connection to my host. I am working on a method to check if the host is gone or still available. So I start a thread which checks if the connection is available.

If the host is gone the thread closes the socket in my asynctask for a possible reconnect. That is working fine and im a lil proud but now the tricky part.

In Java I can close the socket with `Socket.close()` and the blocking readline method will be catched by an exception.

In Android I have to call `Socket.shutdownInput()` to break the readline block and catch the `exception`. Because the try to close the `inputstream` (`BufferedReader`) has no effect for this case. Even if I close the socket the readline is still active and blocking.

Can anyone please explain this behavior? I know I have to stick to closing conditions but this behavior is very different.

EDIT: Thx to yorkw for the link. Its the exact same issue because theres Froyo running on my phone.

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888895/how-to-disconnect-an-httpurlconnection-on-htc-froyo-and-below-phones) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking SO_LINGER time on both android side and on your server side. You should ideally get an IOException on your server side after SO_LINGER on Andoroid + SO_LINGER on server. 
If this does not helps to really check if your Async tasks are indeed closing the sockets try doing the same activity many times and see if you get an exception that says maximum open files exceeded. At least then you'll know that the problem is on Android side.

Comment: My discribed problem was because of Froyo. Its not possible to close a socketstream asynchronosly by another thread in version 2.2. with standard closing conditions known from Java. You have to call Socket.shutdownInput() or Socket.shutdownOutput(). Thats worked for me, other people say thats not working at all... Anyway with a standard close() call on the streams they will remain active, even if u close the socket.